# Getting 'Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking cy commands in that promise.' error when overwriting cy.visit

Tags: javascript, cypress, onload, testautomationfx

I am trying to overwrite the Cypress visit method so that it can close the toast when the page is loaded. This is a draft which is trying just to get the element's length.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalVisit, url, options = {}) => {
    options.onLoad = () => {
        const len = cy.get(BasePage.genericLocators.notificationToasts.releaseVersionToast).its.length;
        console.log(len);
    };
    return originalVisit(url, options);
});
```

Continuously facing the following error:

```
Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.
```

The command that returned the promise was:

```js
cy.visit()
```

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

```js
cy.get()
```

Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.

Cypress will resolve your command with whatever the final Cypress command yields.

This is an error instead of a warning because Cypress internally queues commands serially whereas Promises execute as soon as they are invoked. Attempting to reconcile this would prevent Cypress from ever resolving.

Comment: You could try changing your first line inside onload to this ```cy.get(BasePage.genericLocators.notificationToasts.releaseVersionToast).then((len) => { // check length here})```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use Cypress queued commands such as `cy.get()` inside a callback like `onload()`, but you could use `Cypress.$()` instead.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalVisit, url, options = {}) => {
  options.onLoad = () => {
    const toast = Cypress.$(BasePage.genericLocators.notificationToasts.releaseVersionToast);
    console.log(toast.length);
  };
  return originalVisit(url, options);
});
```

although since the element is a toast, you probably won't catch it like that since there is no retry on `Cypress.$()`.

---

**Commands with retry**

Alternatively, just run your `onload` code sequentially in the test.

```js
cy.visit('/')
cy.get(BasePage.genericLocators.notificationToasts.releaseVersionToast)
  .should('be.visibile') 
  .click()                  // close the toast
```

Using `.should('be.visibile')` would be necessary to catch a transitory element such as a toast message.

---

**As a command overwrite**

You can do the above inside the command overwrite by using a `cy.wrap()`, but if you need to use the window object after `cy.visit()` you will need to re-wrap that.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalVisit, url, options = {}) => {
  return cy.wrap(originalVisit(url, options))
    .then((win) => {
      
      // click the toast away      
      cy.get(BasePage.genericLocators.notificationToasts.releaseVersionToast)
        .should('be.visibile') 
        .click();

      //re-wrap the win so that cy.visit() has same return value as before
      cy.wrap(win)
    })
})

cy.visit('/')
  .then(win => {
    // can use AUT window here as usual
  })
```

**Note** standard `cy.visit()` already waits for the page load event to fire, so you don't need to explicitly do that.